# Calculating PF of a transformer

Tags: transformer, power-factor-correction

> Consider a one-phase transformer rated at 20 MVA, 13/2 kV and 50 Hz.
> It goes through a short-circuit test with |V1|=11 kV applied on the primary side. During the test, the
> primary side draws rated current and 8 MW.
>
> Calculate cos Ф.

Hi, I have a problem that I'm not quite understanding. It's asking me to calculate the power factor, I tried a few approaches.
First by taking "P/S = cos(phi)" -> 8MW/20MVA = 0.4, which is incorrect.

Then I tried to take S/V to get the rated current; 20MVA/13kV = 1538.46 A. Then taking the rated current and multiplying it with the rated voltage of the transformer, but it ended up giving me a wrong answer as well. I do not have the right answer.

How would I go to solve this problem?

Comment: Power factor doesn't depend on rating, it depends on the currently applied voltage and current.

Answer (score 1):

Use the applied 11kV and rated current to find S, and then the pf.